# Use column formatting to customize SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, formatting

I'm following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#formatting-items-based-on-arbitrary-dates-advanced

I have an SP List with Renewal Date and would like to be it marked if the date is smaller than today-31 days so I modified the example from the article to:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Renewal_x0020_Date] <= @now - 2678400000‬, '#ff0000', '')"
  }
}
```

So, according to "to add a day to a date, you'd add (24*60*60*1000 = 86,400,000)" I multiply this by 31.

Unfortunately, the JSON doesn't format my view.

Could someone direct me, please?

Thanks

Slawek

Comment: Go to list settings(Gear>List settings), click on RenewalDate column and see internal name of column in url (...&Field=RenewalDate). Try with $RenewalDate

Answer (score 0):

Column formatting seems to be working for modern experience only. Here are the results.

> **New/Modern Experience**

[image]

> **Classic Experience:**

[image]

So Try switching the experience if your list is currently set to open in classic view.

Comment: For classic view use JSlink https://nearbaseline.com/2013/12/sharepoint-list-conditional-formatting-with-jslink/

Comment: Yeah @Marko Tica

Answer (score 0):

First example with `$RenewalDate`
Try with this ternary (?) operator code

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": {
         "operator": "?",
         "operands": [
            {
               "operator": "<=",
               "operands": [
                  "[$RenewalDate]",
                  {
                     "operator": "+",
                     "operands": [
                        "@now",
                        -2678400000
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "#ff0000",
            ""
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Second example is column with space in name `$Renewal_x0020_Date`

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "style": {
      "color": {
         "operator": "?",
         "operands": [
            {
               "operator": "<=",
               "operands": [
                  "[$Renewal_x0020_Date]",
                  {
                     "operator": "+",
                     "operands": [
                        "@now",
                        -2678400000
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            "#ff0000",
            ""
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT:
using the Excel-style expression syntax

Column without space `$RenewalDate`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$RenewalDate] <= @now - 2678400000, '#ff0000', '')"
  }
}
```

Column with space `$Renewal_x0020_Date`

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$Renewal_x0020_Date] <= @now - 2678400000, '#ff0000', '')"
  }
}
```